Efficient way to delete columns and rows from a numpy array using slicing and not np.delete
Would it be possible given an array A, bad row indices and bad column indices to use slicing to make a new array that does not have these rows or columns?
This can be done with np.delete as follows:
import numpy as np
A=np.random.rand(20,16)
bad_col=np.arange(0,A.shape[1],4)[1:]
bad_row=np.arange(0,A.shape[0],4)[1:]
Anew=np.delete(np.delete(A,bad_row,0),bad_col,1)
print('old shape ',A.shape)
print('new shape ',Anew.shape)


I also know that you can use slicing to select certain columns and rows from an array. But I'm wondering if it can be used to exclude certain column and rows? and if not what the best way besides np.delete to do that.
EDIT: Based on comments, it might not be possible with slicing in place. How about creating a new array with advanced indexing?
It can be done with the following code but slow, looking for a faster alternative:
good_col = [i for i in range(A.shape[1]) if i==0 or i % 4 != 0]
good_row=[ i for i in range(A.shape[0]) if i==0 or i % 4 != 0]

Anew2=A[good_row,:][:,good_col]
print('new shape ',Anew2.shape)

Thank you

Unlike slicing, indexing creates copies. So for large arrays (e.g., over a million elements), there will be no significant performance difference between the two. A possible alternative is to create an index mapping as a second array, and manually map the index when you access it. However, this is a non-contiguous memory access, so it could actually slow down the rest of the code. It will be useful only when you need a few elements.

np.delete uses some sort of copy with a boolean mask or advanced indexing to return a new array. Details vary with how the 'delete' items are specified.  To have any chance of getting a fast view you have to focus on what you want to keep, not on what you want to delete.

You cannot remove items of an array without either moving all items (which is slow for large arrays) or creating a new one. There is no other solution.
In Numba or Cython, you can directly create a new array with one operation instead of 2 so it should be about twice faster for large arrays. It should be even faster for small arrays because Numpy functions have a significant overhead for small arrays.
Numpy views are either contiguous or strided. There is no way to use a variable stride along a given axis. This has been defined that way for sake of performance. Thus, if you want to select only columns and rows with an even ID, you can (because there is a constant stride for each axis that can be set for the resulting view). However, you cannot select all rows/columns avec an ID that is not divisible by 4 for example (because there are no view that can be built with a constant stride).
Note that if you try to cheat by creating new dimension and then flatten the view, then Numpy will create a copy (because there is no other way).

I see. That makes sense. If I'm okay creating a new array similar to what np.delete does. Is there a way to use advanced indexing to exclude the "bad_cols and bad_rows" or would I need to have the indices represent the "good_cols and good_rows" to perform the operation? Thank you.

You can indeed select all the rows and cols you want using indexing of the good columns instead of deleting the bad ones but this dual operation has a similar behaviour: it performs a copy. However, AFAIK you can do that with one operation instead of two (using probably something like np.take) but this is slower in practice for 2D arrays (not yet optimized unfortunately).

If performance is critical, then you can write your own implementation in Cython/Numba but you should not expect a huge improvement (certainly <2x).

Generally, the best solution is not to remove the row/columns but mark them as deleted using either a mask or a user-defined data structure. Then your algorithm has to check the mask or data structure so to not to consider these rows/columns. This removes the need for expensive copies. It can significantly improve the algorithmic complexity of the resulting algorithm.

I can do it with the following code but it is slow, do you have a recommendation of a faster way:
`good_col = [i for i in range(A.shape[1]) if i==0 or i % 4 != 0]
good_row=[ i for i in range(A.shape[0]) if i==0 or i % 4 != 0]
Anew2=A[good_row,:][:,good_col]
print('new shape ',Anew2.shape)`

You can vectorize this by generating all indices and then removing them with np.delete too. Another solution is to use multiple np.arange, concatenate them and sort them which is certainly significantly more expensive though it might be still faster than a non-vectorized solution. Yet another solution is to cheat with setdiff1d so to generate all indices and quickly remove the set of excluded ones. In practice, for this, I would use Numba or Cython personally because all Numpy solutions I can think of are fundamentally pretty inefficient compared to using Cython/Numba.
